# Почему компилятор TypeScript ругается на отсутствие свойства класса, если это свойство в нем есть?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Почему компилятор TypeScript ругается на отсутствие свойства класса, если это свойство в нем есть?

> Property 'path' does not exist on type 'TutorService'.

```
this.tutorServiceService.getTutorServices()
      .then(tutorServices => {
        tutorServices.find(s => `/service/${s.path}` == this.router.url) // Property 'path' does not exist on type 'TutorService'.
      });
```

Вот откуда берется метод getTutorServices():

```
getTutorServices(): Promise<TutorService[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json().data as TutorService[])
       .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

И сам проблемный класс:

```
export class TutorService {
    id: number;
  title: string;
  menuTitle: string;
  sinosis: string;
  text: string;
  path: string; 
}
```

---

Странно. Перезагрузил Webpack (а точнее компилятор Ангуляра2 - ng) и ошибка больше не тревожит. Как так???

Comment: Чтобы дополнить вопрос, жмите кнопку [edit]. :)

Comment: Вообще-то решение данного вопроса и есть - ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКА компилятора. Нет?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _перезагрузкой_ компилятора?

Comment: Нажать Ctrl+C два раза. А потом заново подать команду npm start (запуститься компилятор ng serve в режиме watch)